# I'm trying to Multi-thread a MD5 Hash string method but getting the error CS0123 C# No overload for matches delegate 'ThreadStart'

Tags: c#, string, multithreading, methods

I have done some research and found solutions that apply to a void method, however I have been unable to replicate my code to that of a void as there is no overload for my method '**MD5**' that matches the delegate '**ThreadStart**', and I have been unable to convert a void to string, this programs intent is to show how multi-threading can allow for more than one process can be done at once. I intend to add additional processes on different threads, however, it is important that this works.

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;//Added to allow for UTF8 encoding 
using System.Threading;//Added to allow for multi-threading 

namespace MTSTask5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    //MD5 Hash method 
    public void MD5(string input)
    {
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        //Convert the input string to a byte array and computer the hash, return the hexadecimal  
        byte[] bytes = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
        string result = BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", string.Empty);
        return result.ToLower();

    }

    private void btnStartHash_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int loopQty = Int32.Parse(txtboxLoopQty.Text);

        int i = 0;
        //Create a while loop for the MD5 method below 
        while (i < loopQty)
        {
            //loop output
            string HashOutput = MD5(MD5(txtboxHashOne.Text + txtboxHashTwo.Text));
            txtboxHashOutput.Text = HashOutput + " " + i;
            Thread HashThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MD5));
            HashThread.Start();
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code is strange, you call `MD5()` sequentially, waiting for it to end and after that try to start a thread that does it again? anyway, `ThreadStart` is a delegate without parameters (as you already know), but you want to give `MD5()` an input string. To use the same call as two lines above you could start the thread like `Thread HashThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => MD5(MD5(txtboxHashOne.Text + txtboxHashTwo.Text))));`

Comment: I have changed "**Thread HashThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MD5));**" to  "**Thread HashThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(MD5));**" and I am met with the same error.

Comment: Yes, because `ParameterizedThreadStart` takes an `object`, not a `string` like `MD5(string input)`.

Comment: Thank you @RenéVogt I have removed the addition of doing the MD5 hash twice as it lead to a memory leak error, as you said it is strange, it was the point to make it as intensive on the system as possible. Thank you for the fix.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions that may help you troubleshoot and solve your problem:

First, I believe you may be trying to return `result.ToLower()`, a data type of `string` from your method named `MD5`, I'm guessing you were trying to use this instead of returning `void`, (i.e. nothing):

```
//MD5 Hash method 
public string MD5(string input)
{
    MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    //Convert the input string to a byte array and computer the hash, return the hexadecimal  
    byte[] bytes = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
    string result = BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", string.Empty);
    return result.ToLower();
}
```

---

That may not the entire problem,  so let's check to make sure your method is working by copying the code you have in your `btnStartHash_Click` method into a safe place, and then replacing it with a simple message to yourself.

```
private void btnStartHash_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //Convert the input string to a byte array and computer the hash, return the hexadecimal  and display it in a message box
   MessageBox.Show(MD5("abcdefg"));//parse whatever known value test
}
```

---

> If you are still unsure of the hash result from your MD5 method, then start taking parts out one by one.

---

Build the button click up again once you're certain of desired MD5 method's output:

```
private void btnStartHash_Click_(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtboxHashOne.Text = MD5(txtboxHashInput.Text);
    string hashOfHash = MD5(txtboxHashOne.Text);
    txtboxHashTwo.Text = hashOfHash;
}
```

In the above situation I'm using the MD5 method to hash the input textbox, `txtboxHashInput.Text` and then change the `txtboxHashOne` text box to reflect the change on the form.   The `txboxHashOne`'s entire string is then hashed to make sure to make the `hashOfHash` string.

---

Instead of having each instance `txtboxHashOne` , `txtboxHashTwo`,  one *may*  think it could do better by just creating the text box programmatically on the form:

```
//lets say the loopqty input is the number of times I wanted to hash this
int numberOfTimesToHash = Int32.Parse(txtboxLoopQty.Text);

//x and y represent where you want them to start appearing on your form..
int x = 10;
int y = 100;
int howeverManyThreadsIWant = numberOfTimesToHash;

for (int i = 0; i < howeverManyThreadsIWant; i++) 
{
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
    textBox.Location = new Point(x, y);


    //Could go into a recursive function such as` MD5(Input,recursionDepth)
    //But instead going to reprint same hash for demonstration purposes


    textBox.Text = MD5(txtboxHashInput.Text);
    //MessageBox.Show(textBox.Text);
    this.Controls.Add(textBox);
    y += 30;
}
```

---

Then, the programmer may want to try to embrace a multithreaded approach to reduce complexity we have to do a lot more.

For example, ***unfortunately it's not so simple to do this:***

```
//##!!Don't do this!!
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            int x = 10;
            int y = 100;
            int howeverManyThreadsIWant = numberOfTimesToHash;
            for (int i = 0; i < howeverManyThreadsIWant; i++) 
            {
                TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
                textBox.Tag = i;
                textBox.Location = new Point(x, y);

                //Could go into a recursive function such as MD5(Input,recursionDepth)
                //But instead going to simply reprint same hash
                textBox.Text = MD5(txtboxHashInput.Text);
                //MessageBox.Show(textBox.Text);
                this.Controls.Add(textBox);//<--invalid operations error
                y += 30;
            }

        });
        thread.Start();
```

would result in:

> > System.InvalidOperationException: '**Cross-thread operation not valid**: Control 'Form1' **accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on**.'<<

Strongly consider if you really need multithreading to solve this task.

---

> > Microsoft suggests:

**When to Use Multiple Threads**

Multithreading can be used in many common situations to significantly improve the responsiveness and usability of your application.

**You should strongly consider using multiple threads to:**

```
#Communicate over a network, for example to a Web server, database, or remote   object.
#Perform time-consuming local operations that would cause the UI to freeze.
#Distinguish tasks of varying priority.
#Improve the performance of application startup and initialization.
```

**It is useful to examine these uses in more detail.**

**Communicating Over a Network**

```
#Smart-clients may communicate over a network in a number of ways, including:
#Remote object calls, such as DCOM, RPC or .NET remoting
#Message-based communications, such as Web service calls and HTTP requests
#Distributed transactions
```

---

**With that in mind, *if you really need to do these things***, now that you have bug free code that is hashing the way you want it, visit the [Using Multiple Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649143.aspx) by Microsoft.

Also you may want to check out [Threading in Windows Forms](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml), this has an example that you can run with most of what you need to know.

Hopefully some of this was what you were looking for.